# Flask template filter to exclude certain commands

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, escaping, html-escape-characters

Hello i have something like this for a flask app:

```py
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    user={'name':"{{session.username}}",'secret':"KEY{USE_ESCAPE_STRING!}"}
    if request.args.get('name'):
        user['name'] = request.args.get('name')
    template = '''<div class="jumbotron text-center"> <h2>Hello %s!</h2> <h3>You should not be here...</h3> </div> ''' % user['name']
    return render_template_string(template, user=user)
```

Using this implementation i can run commands like so :
`/test?name={{url_for.__globals__.os.popen(%27ls%27).read()}}`

My question is i can make any filter to exclude commands like `rm/rmdir`?

Comment: if you want to make it safe then don't use `""" %s """ % user['name']`

Comment: BTW: someone can create complex command like `ls;rm` (or use codes instead chars) and you will have problem to find `rm` `rmdir` in string. You could remove command `rm`, `rmdir` from system but someone can find other function which can make problem. Better don't use it at all or use `if/else` to accept very simple words which will activate only tested functions - ie. "show_folder"` activate function which runs `ls`

Comment: The idea is that i am making a capture the flag challenge and the """%s""" i used was on purpose, because you need to access some files to run a python script to get a key and now i need an ideea how to make this a bit safer

Comment: you could add this information in question. When people know why you need to use something unsafe then they may suggest different solution.

Comment: on some servers you can run code using virtual machine [docker](https://www.docker.com/get-started) which separate your code. And youhave to add manually all commands which you want to use inside docker - ie. `ls`, `grep`, etc. If you don't add `rm`, `rmdir` to docker then it will be safe. But even if you add `rm` in docker then it can delete only elements inside docker but elements outside docker are safe. Docker keep all code in container which you can duplicate to keep original version and run it when something went wrong or if you want to run the same code on other computer.